# "URL Parts Error" with inetc::post in nsis

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm using nsis for developing an installer. As the last step there is a registration process for the user to get his email address and some other data and send it to a server. The code is as follows.

```
StrCpy $ContactName "$0"
StrCpy $ContactEmail "$1"
StrCpy $Coments "$2"
StrCpy $Updates "$3"
StrCpy $PostStr "userName=$ContactName&userEmail=$ContactEmail&userComments=$Coments&updates=$Updates"

inetc::post "$PostStr" "http://www.mysite.com/registration/registerAcceptor.php" "$INSTDIR\output.txt"

Pop $0
StrCmpS $0 "OK" success failedToSubmit
failedToSubmit:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "There was an error submitting the registration information"
Return

success:
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "Your information was successfully received by OrangeHRM"
```

But for the fist time when the user is trying to register it gives the error message as

```
"There was an error submitting the registration information"
```

And when I check the return value of the command using the message as follows

```
MessageBox MB_OK $0
```

it shows the following error

```
URL Parts Error
```

But when I go back and proceed with the same action it gives the success message and the return value is also as

```
OK
```

I'm not sure why this thing acts two separate ways in these two scenarios. Can someone help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding "/END" to the plugin call as suggested in [this forum thread](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=343328) (There might be other things on the stack and the plugin does not know when to stop reading, this would explain why it works the second time around)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the `inetc` NSIS plugin, but the difference was that I used `/END` already and it didn't work in same cases somewhat. After I had read that the issue is related to unclear stack, I checked my code and there were many calls to various functions, which left the stack cluttered with variables. Because even the fact I transmitted the `/END` didn't help, I tried to clear the stack manually from all variables with code from internet before each call to inetc, and that worked out as magic.

So here is the code:

```
!macro ClearStack
    ${Do}
        Pop $0
        IfErrors send
    ${Loop}
send:
!macroend

!define ClearStack "!insertmacro ClearStack"
```

you can use it as a macro to avoid any duplications, or just copy-paste right in the place you need to send something with inetc.